# Prompting for user input during ArcGIS Python script tool execution?

Tags: arcpy, gui, tool-validation

I want to prompt for user input after all parameters have been specified for the script tool. I've seen many forum posts and stackexchange questions about this, and they all conclude that it's unnecessary, but I think my case is an exception. I want to give the user an opportunity to confirm data, such as how many sets of GPS coordinates there are. They will be yes/no questions ("is this data obviously incorrect?"), and the script tool parameter input form doesn't seem like it'd work well for this.

I know Tkinter's event handler causes problems with ArcGIS, and other framworks have similar problems. One workaround I found is to have your script call another script that runs as a separate process, and display the GUI from the second process, but that seems a little too hackish.

---

Apparently wxPython *does* work, but it's not included with python. I need to be able to distribute these scripts without any extra requirements other than ArcGIS, so that wouldn't work for me.

---

To clarify, the most important use would be to prompt the user when my software validation checks can't validate the data. For example, I have a list of IDs that I want to validate, but the format isn't consistent. I want to be able to prompt the user with a yes/no dialog if I can't validate in software (eg. the ID doesn't match one of the common patterns). It's possible that new ID formats will be created without my knowledge.

---

Another example: I have a file that contains, among other things, a table of start & stop times. I want to validate each row of the table individually, and cramming all of that data, plus the other checks, into the warning window would get ugly fast.

Comment: I would advise against it. Script tools are meant to be able to run without user interaction once you hit "Run". You might be able to provide more pertinent warning/error messages using [validation code](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00150000000t000000), however.

Comment: You mention calling a sub-process as hackish, but as far as getting user input, I think this might be your only option if you're sticking with python script tools.  The way that I would do it, if I absolutely had to have user interaction with a python script tool, is by calling a C# sub-process.  If I recall, the python code will halt and wait for the sub-process to complete before continuing.  This gives you the opportunity to include a limitless amount of user interaction built in C#.  You can't pass objects to C# though, so you would have to get your data over in string form.

Comment: Although for the record I agree with blah238

Comment: This is exactly what validation in script tools is for.

Comment: I thought the validation is only for scripted validation, and can't get user input? Can I display yes/no prompts from the validator, or something else that would have the same effect?

Comment: Regarding your latest edit, that doesn't sound like a convincing use case. Just add a warning message (or error message if you don't want the tool to be runnable).

Comment: blah238, one problem with the built in warnings is that only a few fields are being validated, but they are file selection fields and there's a long list of checks that are run against each file. One file contains a table of start and stop times, and the current specs say I need to validate each row individually.

Comment: Are the checks against the table really necessary to do at validation time or can they be deferred to runtime? You don't really want to be hitting the file system/network much during validation because it runs so frequently.

Comment: No, and I actually moved all of the validation to the main script. I still don't have any native way to display dialog windows, so I created a separate script that displays a dialog window.

Comment: So what about a script where I'd like to have my user be able to enter different parameters for the script? i.e. they're performing IDW interpolation for example but I would like to have simple input prompts for the Power, Neighbors and Reach settings, what's the best way to set that up? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, does this option can work for you or not, but may be you can think about creating a c# application.

1. Do all user interaction and data validation through this application.
2. After validating all data, run the python script.