# 'Pausing' a Python script tool to allow the user to provide input before continuing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I am using ArcGIS. I have written a Python script that creates various surfaces including NDVI. After the script creates those surfaces, I would like the script to stop running while the user manually:

1. examines the NDVI and other outputs from the first part of the script
2. creates a feature class
3. and edits the feature class to add some point features at appropriate locations.

Once the user is done creating and editing the point feature class, I want the script to keep going.

Is this possible?

Comment: You should be able to achive this by strategically placing the `raw_input` function in your script. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

Comment: related: [Prompt for user input during ArcGIS python script execution](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46804/prompt-for-user-input-during-arcgis-python-script-execution)

Answer (score 9):

Since step three is a manual editing of features based on looking at the NDVI image I would recommend creating two scripts.

1. For the first script, doing what you've done already and also adds the NDVI image into ArcMap (part of step 1) and creates the feature class (step 2)
2. Second script runs after you are done with your third step.